# How to resize an image for different orientations of iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiimageview, orientation

IPad application coded for showing images. Images are showing in a UIImageView. Aplication should resize images according to the different oriention of the iPad. How to resize images for this purpose.

```
fullPhoto.fullImageBefore = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 200, 350, 350)]autorelease];
NSString *image1 = fullPhoto.patient.imageBefore;
fullPhoto.fullImageBefore.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image1];
[fullPhoto.view addSubview:fullPhoto.fullImageBefore];
[image1 release];
[fullPhoto release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set the `fullImageBefore.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;`

```
fullImageBefore.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

your viewController should implement:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It works, but it only resizing the width of the image. Are there any additional things to be done.